# Regex named conditional lookahead (in Python)

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements, named, regex-lookarounds

I'm hoping to match the beginning of a string differently based on whether a certain block of characters is present later in the string. A very simplified version of this is:

```
re.search("""^(?(pie)a|b)c.*(?P<pie>asda)$""", 'acaaasda')
```

Where, if `<pie>` is matched, I want to see `a` at the beginning of the string, and if it isn't then I'd rather see `b`.

I'd use normal numerical lookahead but there's no guarantee how many groups will or won't be matched between these two.

I'm currently getting `error: unknown group name`. The sinking feeling in my gut tells me that this is because what I want is impossible (look-ahead to named groups isn't exactly a feature of a *regular* language parser), but I really really really want this to work -- the alternative is scrapping 4 or 5 hours' worth of regex writing and redoing it all tomorrow as a recursive descent parser or something.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What kind of text are you searching/parsing?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't see any `pie` out there in your string. Can you some sample input with corresponding output?

Comment: can you post your real text with what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: Pasting seems to ruin formatting and goes over character limit regardless. 

But what I'm getting at is that I have a quantity, `(?P<amt>%s|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+|([0-9]+\s+)?[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)`, (where %s is `one`, `two`, `a`, etc) a unit of measure, and then some other stuff. A quantity doesn't have to be present if you have a partitive construction though, as in "pinch of salt" or "aroma of vermouth". Since I'm using this to classify lines as well as parse, it's important that I catch those as well, lest they be considered `instruction` or `name` rather than `ingredient_line`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to do what you want to do with named groups.  If you don't mind duplication *too* much, you could duplicate the shared conditions and `OR` the expressions together:

```
^(ac.*asda|bc.*)$
```

If it is a complicated expression you could always use string formatting to share it (rather than copy-pasting the shared part):

```
common_regex = "c.*"
final_regex = "^(a{common}asda|b{common})$".format(common=common_regex)
```

Comment: I think this is what I might end up doing. It also strikes me that I could probably just rewrite some of the other regexes so that they require a backwards look at the `amt` name (see above snippet in reply).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
^(?:a(?=c.*(?P<pie>asda)$)|b)c.*$
```

or without `.*$` if you don't need it.